# Congruent Squares Question using algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving, congruences, word-problem

I am also struggling with this question where I don't know how to use my knowledge of congruency to work out the length of the longer side.

I thought the longest side would be a+x but it was wrong.
How would I work out the length for this square.

Question:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that I'm assuming that x is the side length of the inner square even though it looks like another line was highlighted.

Let's call the smaller length of one rectangle *w* and the longer length *l*

So here are the formulas we know:

*a*=*l*+*w*

For x we can see that two upright triangles on either side of the square span out to length *a* therefore:

*x*=*a*-*2w*

Now all we need to do is solve the equation below by substituting a for its formula:

*x*=(*l*+*w*)- *2w*

*x*+*2w*=*l*+*w*

*x*-*w*=*l*

However. This is not over. Because we have to do this in terms of *x* and *a*. We cannot use *w*. We can simply re-arrange the formula for *x* (*x*=*a*-*2w*) to do that.

*w*=(*a*-*x*)/2

Now we replace *w* in the 'final' equation with its formula:

*x*-((*a*-*x*)/2)=*l*